# SQL: How to select users that have purchased ONLY a certain product?

Tags: sql

Say I have a table that looks like the following

```
CUSTOMER     PURCHASES
James        Basketball
James        Football
Alex         Basketball
```

How would I select customers that have only purchased a basketball?
ie only Alex. Thanks for any help or advice.

Comment: `COUNT` + `GROUP BY` + `HAVING` (+ may be `DISTINCT` in case if one customer may purchase the same product twice and it's a valid case for you)

Comment: i am keenly interested in what you tried before you asked this one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one way that using standard SQL;

```
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM Table1
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
  AND MAX(PURCHASES)='Basketball'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c180/1).

If the customer may have purchased more than one basketball, you can replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT Purchases)`.

If you go database specific, a more readable option may be `EXCEPT` or `MINUS`, here an SQL server version;

```
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM Table1 WHERE PURCHASES='Basketball'
EXCEPT
SELECT CUSTOMER FROM Table1 WHERE PURCHASES<>'Basketball'
```

...which will do the same thing as the latter (may have purchased more than one basketball) case.

Comment: My first thought was the first option.  I didn't think of the second, which I also really like!  I wonder what the performance implications are between the two for each of the popular sql implementations.

Comment: I used the first option you provided and it worked out. Just wondering though, why did you use MAX for MAX(PURCHASES)='Basketball'?  Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @user2853262 In standard SQL, you can't use just `"Purchases"` in a `HAVING`clause unless you're grouping by it or using it in an aggregate function (like `MIN`/`MAX`/`AVG`/...). In this case (there only being one result per group), `MAX` and `MIN` would give the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from purchase 
group by customer 
having count(*) = 1 
   and purchases = 'BasketBall';`
```

Working example

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe6ee/1

Comment: Works, but is MySQL specific since you're comparing directly to `PURCHASES` without using a `GROUP BY` or an aggregate function on it.

Comment: Since I am comparing `purchases`, I need to put a `select *` instead of the `customer` column alone.

Comment: @cppcoder: regardless of what you need it exactly for - it's not ansi sql compilant and uses mysql's sql extension.